# Creating list of unnamed roads on Google Maps and match them with own road dataset

Tags: qgis, shapefile, google-maps, road, arcgis-roads-highways

I am looking to update Google Maps road network in my city, but it seems I can't find the unnamed roads so I can quickly find the matching roads in my dataset that has names for both old and new roads.

As a background, Google Maps AI always detects roads that have been developed, but those roads don't have names while the city road department has a shapefile with names. Can I find those specifically unnamed roads using an API maybe? How should I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried OSM roads instead?  You can use the quick OSM plugin to download the road.

Comment: Yes, but OSM might have the correct names. My intention is to find unnamed roads on Google Maps so I can update its road network.

Comment: @GforGIS for OP's goal, using OSM data makes no sense as the task is to contribute to improve Google Maps data with additional info that OP already has

Comment: @Babel, thanks for the clarification. I thought it was his/her own data.